# Thread Pooling and InheritedThreadLocal

Tags: java, threadpool, thread-local, inherited

I have seen the below question.The answer was to use the semaphores instead.This didnot answer one of the other problems stated in the question which I am facing.

[Using InheritableThreadLocal with ThreadPoolExecutor -- or -- a ThreadPoolExecutor that doesn't reuse threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9012371/using-inheritablethreadlocal-with-threadpoolexecutor-or-a-threadpoolexecut)

I have a parent thread which sets some unique identifier for each new request in an InhertiedThreadLocal and submits 2 Runnable Tasks to the ThreadPool i.e for 2 threads.
For the initial request the values that are set for InheritedThreadLocal in the parent thread are propagated to the ChildThread correctly.
For the next requests,the childthreads are not receiving the latest InheritedThreadLocal set by the parent Thread and the old values in the ChildThread are used.

This is because threadpool reuses threads and the InheritedThreadLocal are copied only when new thread is created.

Now how can I propagate the latest value of InheritedThreadLocal from parent to Child thread in the thread pool scenario.
Is there a way out for this ?

Comment: I tried googling,but couldnt find a specific yes if this can be solved.

Comment: I am facing the same problem. Did you find a solution to this finally? If yes, please add it as an answer.

Comment: @rahulmohan Somehow we did not proceed with the above requirement and hence we did not try this further.http://stackoverflow.com/a/7297494/745018 check this if it helps you.

Comment: The point is only when a child thread is created,the parent threads thread local values will be passed to child thread.Once this child thread returns to the pool after initial execution or executes multiple times from there on,it cannot access the parent thread context.

Comment: https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/java/TPS04-J.+Ensure+ThreadLocal+variables+are+reinitialized+when+using+thread+pools

Answer (score 2):

I wrote these methods as I needed it.

```
import java.lang.reflect.Constructor;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor;

public class EnvUtils {
    /**
     * Extract the current inheritableThreadLocals map from the current thread.
     * Typical usage is in a threadpool, where:
     * <ul>
     * <li>You run {@link EnvUtils#extract()} in the running thread, to store
     * the information somewhere
     * <li>You create a method {@link ThreadPoolExecutor#beforeExecute()} in which
     * you run {@link EnvUtils#copy(Object)} with the above-stored information.
     * </ul>
     *
     * @return The current inheritableThreadLocals of the current thread
     */
    public static Object extract() {
        Object toreturn = null;
        try {
            // get field descriptor
            Field inthlocalsField = Thread.class.getDeclaredField("inheritableThreadLocals");
            inthlocalsField.setAccessible(true);
            //the object stored there
            Object inthlocalsMap = inthlocalsField.get(Thread.currentThread());
            // no need to copy, it will be done by the copy() method below
            toreturn = inthlocalsMap;
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException | SecurityException | IllegalArgumentException | IllegalAccessException e) {
            // This may happen in a different Java implementation
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        return toreturn;
    }

    /**
     * Replaces the field inheritableThreadLocals of the current thread with the values provided.<br/>
     * It is the same as if the current thread was just created from the thread whose <code>stored</code>
     * values come from.<br/>
     * Must be called in the thread which want to inherit from given {@link inheritableThreadLocals} map.<br/>
     * <b>Note 1:</b> This does not modify non-inheritable thread locals<br/>
     * <b>Note 2:</b> This delete all previous values of {@link inheritableThreadLocals} in the current thread<br/>
     *
     * @param stored
     *            The stored inheritableThreadLocals value, coming from the extract() method
     */
    public static void copy(final Object stored) {
        try {
            // find ThreadLocalMap class
            String threadLocalClassName = ThreadLocal.class.getName();
            Class<?> threadLocaLMapClass = Class.forName(threadLocalClassName + "$ThreadLocalMap");
            // check that given object is an instance of the class
            if (stored == null || !threadLocaLMapClass.isInstance(stored)) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Given object is not a ThreadLocalMap: " + stored);
            }
            // get constructor of ThreadLocalMap
            Constructor<?> creator = threadLocaLMapClass.getDeclaredConstructor(threadLocaLMapClass);
            creator.setAccessible(true);
            // get field descriptor of the thread
            Field inthlocalsField = Thread.class.getDeclaredField("inheritableThreadLocals");
            inthlocalsField.setAccessible(true);
            // create new inherited map
            Object newObj = creator.newInstance(stored);
            // set it to the current thread
            inthlocalsField.set(Thread.currentThread(), newObj);

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | NoSuchMethodException | SecurityException | NoSuchFieldException
                | IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException | InvocationTargetException
                | InstantiationException e) {
            // This may happen in a different Java implementation
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

    }

}
```

`EnvUtils.extract()` returns a reference to the current thread's `inheritableThreadLocals` map.

Now when you create a `Runnable` to be called in a `ThreadPool`, just store in a field `inheritableThreadInfo = EnvUtils.extract()`, and in its `run()` method, just call `EnvUtils.copy(inheritableThreadInfo)`.

**Note:** This solution uses a lot of reflection and as such it is subject to the Java implementation. I tested on Oracle Java 1.8.

Answer (score 0):

If we configure ThreadPoolExecutor like this

```
new ThreadPoolExecutor(0, 2, 0L, TimeUnit.SECONDS, new SynchronousQueue<Runnable>());
```

it will create a new Thread each time thus InheritableThreadLocals will be inherited, though then it can hardly be called a ThreadPoolExecutor

Comment: Ok.Yes in that case that would not be a a thread pool.The point is that we are not using ThreadPoolExecutor for managing threads.We use IBM implementation of javax.resource.spi.work.WorkManager to manager threads.

Comment: To add one more point,the question can be simplified as,Is there any way wherein we can get the InhertiedThreadLocals from the  parent thread context into a child thread context whenever a thread from a threadpool executes a given runnable?